# Why my MySQL table Primary Key does not increase Automatically?

Tags: mysql, database

I am so curious why my table Primary Key does not increase following its sequence?

Before my insertion, my table is:

[image: Before Insertion]

I try to insert one row using:

`` INSERT INTO `wwt_film`.`film` (`film_name`, `film_time`, `director`, `play_time`, `poster_url`, `is_delete`)  VALUES ('test2', '2020-12-24', 'director23', '120', '/img/108.jpg', '1'); ``

I think it should help me insert one row with film_id '19'. However, i get the following table, which has a new row with film_id '38'
[image: After Insertion]
I do not why and can anyone help??

Comment: Did you delete any rows?

Comment: Yes, I have delete rows.

Comment: Then that will be why. Deleting rows does not reset auto increment value. you can reset if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have deleted some rows. deleting rows will not reset the auto-increment value. You can reset it via `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = value`.

Comment: ...but you probably shouldn't. Design your application so gaps do not matter.